# Pusher Real Time Chat Widget not working for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, widget, chat, pusher

I was trying to integrate pusher to my ruby on rails application. However I'm not able to send messages using the steps provided in the tutorial.

Here is what I have accomplished so far:
1. Followed the steps in the tutorial
2. Got the Chat UI to appear for the URL I want to.
3. Got the Demo to work on my localhost, using Sinatara.

What special steps do I have to take for Pusher chat to work for my Ruby On rails application?

Tutorial: http://pusher.com/tutorials/realtime_chat_widget

Comment: Were you ever able to figure out how to get Chat to work with pusher?

Comment: Yes I was. Let me know if I could help you out.

Comment: I am also trying to get the widget to work on my Rails app, and am a bit confused about the Sinatra part - the instructions says to link to this `pusher-realtime-chat-widget/src/ruby-sinatra/chat.rb` file, and I was wondering if adding the ruby-sinatra gem was also required?  If you could detail how you got it to work in your Rails app as one an answer to your own question it'd be great .. thanks!